# How to create function pointer to template member function?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

I have two template classes as below:

```
template<class T>
class pub {
public:
    void fun(T a, T b)
    {
       //do something with a & b
    }
}

template<class T>
class sub
{
private:
    std::set<funPtr> funPtr;
public:

    void fun2( funPtr f)
    {
        funPtr.insert(funPtr);
    }

};
```

I need to get a function pointer to the member function `fun`.

The problem is both the classes are template classes, so I don't know how to do it.

How may I solve this problem in C++?

Comment: what is `funPtr` ?

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki, paradoxically, it is `std::set<funPtr>`.

Comment: Where is foo ? And funPtr is not a type.

Comment: Can you rewrite your question in a way that the names all mean something? There is no type `funPtr` and there is no function `foo`.

Comment: You sure you want a function pointer and not a [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function)?

Comment: Why are you inserting your set into itself?

Answer (score 4):

```
template<typename T>
using funPtr = void (pub<T>::*)(T, T);
```

Usage:

```
std::set<funPtr<T>> funPtrs;
```

Or simply (inside `sub` where the template parameter `T` is visible):

```
using funPtr = void (pub<T>::*)(T, T);
```

and

```
std::set<funPtr> funPtrs;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answers and sorry for the confusion about the definition of funPtr.

Answer (score 2):

```
template<class T>
class sub
{
private:
    // typedef void (pub<T>::*funPtr)(T,T);   // C++98
    using funPtr = void (pub<T>::*)(T,T);     // C++11
    std::set<funPtr> fset;
public:

    void fun2( funPtr f)
    {
        fset.insert(f);
    }
};
```

Comment: Boo for `typedef`, that arcane legacy crutch.

Comment: @shrike, it's time to upgrade to C++11, specially when responding to a question that is tagged C++11.

Comment: @RSahu: did not see the tag... anyway, since it's not deprecated, it's valid answer :-P